# Dijkstra Algorithm: wrong path

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

When I compute paths again as vertex `C to M`

Correct path should be

```
C -> B -> N -> M
```

But it is

```
A -> B -> N -> M
```

I used this code [Dijkstra Algorithm](http://www.algolist.com/code/java/Dijkstra's_algorithm)

This is the picture for my graph:

[image: public static void main]

Comment: what is your graph?!

Comment: You posted neither your actual code nor your graph. How do you expect anyone to help you?

Comment: sorry i can't post more link and more code i editing post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you first call function compute for A then call it for C. some field like this :

```
public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
public Vertex previous;
```

are already have a value, so you need to delete pathcomputation for A or clear this values, you can do it with a function like :

```
public void clear() {
    minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    previous = null;
}
```

inside this Vertex Class, and call it like this :

```
for (Vertex v : vertices) {
    v.clear();
}
```

before `computePaths(v2);`

[here](http://ideone.com/YSpa6U) is a online version of your code, you could see that the output is :

```
Distance to B: 1.0
Path: [A, B]
Distance to M: 5.0
Path: [C, B, N, M]
```